# Select random row for each category in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

| ID | category | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | p1 |
| 2 | 1 | p2 |
| 3 | 1 | p3 |
| 4 | 1 | p4 |
| 5 | 2 | p5 |
| 6 | 2 | p6 |
| 7 | 2 | p7 |
| 8 | 3 | p8 |
| 9 | 3 | p9 |
| 10 | 3 | p10 |

I am trying to select  one random product for each category.

result like this :

| category | product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | p3 |
| 2 | p7 |
| 3 | p8 |

i tried with this query, gives me random but not for each category without duplicates
SELECT
category, product
FROM
table
WHERE
category IN (1,2,3)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT N

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try the following using a sub-query correlated for each category:

```
select category, (
  select product 
  from t t2 
  where t.category = t2.category
  order by rand() limit 1
) product
from t
group by category;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. It removes duplicates but not giving each categories,it can miss a few categories

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by not giving each categories, what is the issue with [this fiddle?](https://dbfiddle.uk/h0iDOD3z)

Comment: my bad, it turns out In my real data there some categories which dont have products. Your solution is also working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows :

```
SELECT t.category, t.product
FROM mytable t
inner join (
  select category, FLOOR((RAND() * (max(ID)-min(ID)+1))+min(ID)) as randomID
  from mytable
  group by category
) as s on s.category = t.category and s.randomID = t.ID
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/55pGrQND)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be to make use of `PARTITION BY`:

```
with tmp as (
select  row_number() over (partition by category 
                           order by RAND() 
                          ) as rn,
        category,
        product
from t
)
select  category , 
        product  
from tmp
where rn = 1
```